# about PATH variable UNIX

Tags: unix

I see in examples of .profile file in UNIX systems, that after giving a value to the PATH variable e.g. `PATH=$PATH:.` and then it is exported `export PATH`.

My question are 2:

1. Why will happen if I don't export PATH after giving it a value?
2. `PATH=$PATH:.` means that the current directory is added to PATH variable. But is this done only 1 time? I mean will it just add my home directory, or every time I change the directory it will add it to PATH?

Comment: Just a warning. Don't add . to the path!! It means the current directory, and always means it, even when you change dir. Meaning if someone had created a program with a commonly used name like ls, and placed it in a dir they had write access to. (Clearly they couldn't put it in /bin), and you change to that dir and try to run ls, it may run the malicious version, which is (clearly) a security risk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't export `PATH`, then when you start another program (or sub-shell), that program will not see the same value for `$PATH` that you have. Exporting it means the value that you see is also seen by the child processes that your shell spawns.

Adding `.` to the `PATH` does not expand into your current directory name when you added it. It stays a `.`. So whatever current directory you happen to be in will be the directory that gets searched for executables when you try to run a program.

Answer (score 3):

1. Probably nothing. Once a variable is exported, it will keep being exported even if reassigned. And it is expected that PATH is already exported when `.profile` is sourced. But, just in case, it is exported anyway. If the variable weren't exported, it would still work in the current shell, but it wouldn't be inherited by any child process.
2. `.` means the current directory, whatever it is, but it is never expanded to the real name of the directory (for that use `pwd` enclosed in back-quotes). If you change the directory, the current directory will be in the path. That is similar to the behavior of other non UNIX-like operating systems (Windows and DOS), but it is generally considered a security risk. To minimize it, at least put it at the end of the PATH, as in your example.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't export a variable, it will remain local to the script that's running, i.e. `.profile` in this case. That means that if you reference `$PATH` anywhere else, it will be empty.

The variable is only set when the statement is executed, i.e. when `.profile` is run. Usually, this will only happen once (when you start the shell) and not when you change directories.